# Cannot use InvokeRepeating with method parameters. How do I work around this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement a damage over time system, but Unity keeps saying "Trying to Invoke method...Couldn't be Called." The method I want to call uses the parameters "Collider coll", but from my research you can't invoke if the method has said paremters.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

public class DamageOverTime : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int PHP; //PHP = Player Health from PlayerHealth.cs script.
    public int Damage; //Amount of damage.
    public int DamageOverTime; //Damage over time.
    public float DamageInterval_DOT = .25f; //Damage interval for damage over time.
    public string Level;
    PlayerHealth player;

    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
        InvokeRepeating("OnTriggerEnter", DamageInterval_DOT, DamageInterval_DOT);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        PHP = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().PlayerHP;

        if (PHP <= 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(Level);
        }

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().PlayerHP = PHP - Damage;
        }

        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Ball")
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(Level);
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to get the OnTriggerEnter function to loop ever 1/4 of a second (or lower possibly). Current upon entering a collider my health is drained by 60% in about a second which is far too fast. How should I work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `InvokeRepeating` with `OnTriggerEnter`, because it's a trigger, which means it will trigger once when entrance of its holder occured.
Also `InvokeRepeating` means that you want to keep repeating an action continously which is not the case here. You want your trigger to occur once and then remove `health points` over time.

### Solution - Coroutine

`Unity3D` makes custom usage of `IEnumerable` and `yield` keyword called `Coroutine` that always returns an `IEnumerator`. How it works? It will return control on every `yield` there is in our `Coroutine` and then will go back to exact point where it gave back control instead of starting function execution from scratch.

### Code:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
{
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        StartCoroutine("DamageOverTimeCoroutine");
    }

    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Ball")
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(Level);
    }
}

public IEnumerator DamageOverTimeCoroutine()
{
    var dotHits = 0;
    while (dotHits < 4)
    {
        //Will remove 1/4 of Damage per tick
        GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().PlayerHP -= Damage / 4;
        dotHits++;
        //Will return control over here
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(DamageInterval_DOT);
        //And then control is returned back here once 0.25s passes
    }
}
```

There's of course room for improvement in this `Coroutine`. You can pass parameters to it, same as you can to any other method in `C#`. Also you can implement other invervals that are not hardcoded. Code above is just a simple example on how to deal with such scenarios.

### For continous damage over time

```
public IEnumerator DamageOverTimeCoroutine()
{
    var dotHits = 0;
    var player = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
    while (true)
    {
        //Stop removing damage, player is dead already
        if (player.PlayerHP <= 0)
            yield break;
        //Will remove 5 Damage per tick
        player.PlayerHP -= 5;
        dotHits++;
        //Will return control over here
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(DamageInterval_DOT);
        //And then control is returned back here once 0.25s passes
    }
}
```

To stop `Coroutine` somewhere else from code use `StopCoroutine("DamageOverTimeCoroutine")` to stop certain coroutine type or `StopAllCoroutines()` to stop all coroutines that are active now.

Comment: I see. I tested it out, and it works, but it only removes 1/4 players health until I re-enter. I want it to continuously drain the health until it reaches 0 UNLESS the player moves out of said trigger. How would I do that?

Comment: You can then go with `while (true)` instead and add `void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)` that will stop the coroutine: `StopCoroutine(DamageOverTimeCoroutine())` when you leave trigger. If you want other coroutines to stop on this event, you might want to call `StopAllCoroutines()` instead. You will also need to check if HP is not 0. You might want to check for it in `while()` clause or check it inside loop and hit `yield break` to break `Coroutine`.

Comment: I have updated my answer so you can see what do I mean.

Comment: Ok. while (true) worked great for continous damage, and to stop it I tried doing StopCoroutine(DamageOverTimeCoroutine());, which didn't stop it, and then I tried to do a tag check ([like so](http://pastebin.com/P4iLUuKi)), but that didn't work either. I would just use StopAllCoroutines(), but I want this to be specific to the player as I may want to add more later. Also in my Update method I have it checking if the players HP is 0, and if it does it will reload the level.

Comment: Try changing to `StartCoroutine("DamageOverTimeCoroutine")` and then also stop it by string with name, not with method signature. If you want to leave method signature style, you need to assign coroutine to variable and then access it with `StopCoroutine`. I have edited my answer for first method (coroutine name) scenario.