# Turret shooting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi i am currently working on a turret shooting script. My bullet shoots boet does not go in the enemy's direction. something is wrong or missing and i cant figure out what. I have looked up alot of solutions but cant find recent ones or good ones.

EDIT:
my enemy's are instantiated so there is multiple of them. would that be part of the problem? if not do i need to provide more details? im kina new to the site so pls forgive me if i do stuff wrong.

```
public GameObject Enemy;
public GameObject Bullet;
public float bulletForce = 100f;

private Vector3 direction;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    ShootFunctionRepeat();  
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    direction = Enemy.transform.position - this.transform.position;

}

void ShootFunctionRepeat()
{
    InvokeRepeating("ShootFunction", 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

void ShootFunction(GameObject Bullet)
{
    GameObject temp = Instantiate(Bullet, this.transform.position + direction.normalized, Quaternion.identity);
    temp.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(direction.normalized * bulletForce);
}
```

Comment: I think the `direction = Enemy.transform.position - this.transform.position;` should be in the `ShootFunction(GameObject Bullet)` method. But this probably doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen tried that, that doesnt work. thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: (wild guessing) What about moving the `temp.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(direction.normalized * bulletForce);` to the Update method. (you need to create a field instead of the local variable GameObject temp)

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Not sure what you mean by making a field. could you explain?

Comment: I think the `AddForce` should not be called ones: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/567934/rigidbody-addforce-in-update.html

Comment: Well, are you setting Enemy in the inspector? How is the program supposed to know which enemy to shoot at? Both answers are based on the asumption that you set Enemy to the correct enemy somewhere else in your Program. I believe that is not true right now. How do you assign Enemy?

Comment: I guess there is my problem. i dont have anything that does that also dont know how to do it. im sorry if i confused you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't work. You need to remove the `GameObject Bullet` paramter from `ShootFunction()` because the paramter hides `this.Bullet`. And also Unity3D will print warning message *Trying to Invoke method: Shoot.ShootFunction couldn't be called.*: you [cannot use `InvokeRepeating` with method parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566954/cannot-use-invokerepeating-with-method-parameters-how-do-i-work-around-this).

Now it works:

[image: example]

I used a bullet prefab assigned to `public GameObject Bullet`. And `public GameObject Enemy` was also assigned a Cube GameObject from the inspector.

[Full project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ip5yj71c7an98zu/Shoot.zip?dl=0).

But you still need to think about how to recycle and finally destroy the bullets: In your code, you just `Instantiate` the bullets, but when will they be destroyed?

Comment: check out the edit on my post. maybe you will be able to help me now. tried this and it did not work. thanks for helping!

Comment: Added link to full project.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to know what **exactly** you are trying to do.
But this will at least fix **most** issues.

1. You must always normalize your vectors before they can be used as a
   direction. A direction is a vector with a magnitude of 1. If you
   simply subtract one location from another you don't get a
   normalized vector.
2. I am not sure if your ShootFunction is
   allowed to have a parameter. I don't think so. Access you member
   (Bullet) directly.
3. I also removed an offset in your instantiation location. You might need to add it back in. But I believe it is not necessary.

Sample

```
public GameObject Enemy;
public GameObject Bullet;
public float bulletForce = 100f;

private Vector3 direction;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    ShootFunctionRepeat();  
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    direction = (Enemy.transform.position - this.transform.position).normalized;    
}

void ShootFunctionRepeat()
{
    InvokeRepeating("ShootFunction", 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

void ShootFunction()
{
    GameObject temp = Instantiate(Bullet, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    temp.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(direction.normalized * bulletForce);
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem. i edited the post where i explained it a bit better.thanks for helping.